# Heroku version not set despite following guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to push a rails 5 app to Heroku and I believe that I followed the instructions on the Heroku page:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

$ cat Gemfile
.....
ruby "2.3.1"

$ heroku run bash
$ env | grep PATH
PATH=/app/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

$ git push heroku master
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
```

which terminates with the error:

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `symbolize_keys' for #       <String:0x007fac0655feb0>
remote:           /tmp/build_39bfaebc9acd5a6bcb91a69f2b13c171/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems /railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:393:in `secrets'
```

Which I guess it is because it is using 2.2 and not 2.3.

The version in /bin is 1.9.3 so in case it would not find any, it should use 1.9.3 and not 2.2.4.

The error message above was fixed with the help of spickermann. Removing the secret.yml file from git tracking allowed the app to be deployed without errors.

Still, the wrong Ruby version persists and Heroku even returns a warning at the end:

```
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
remote:        To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
remote:        ruby '2.2.4'
remote:        # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-     versions for more information.
```

Any advice about what else can be done?

Thank you!

Comment: I forgot to mention that bin/bundle is exactly as stated in the guide

Comment: $ bundler --version
Bundler version 1.13.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your deployment fails because your `config/secret.yml` is not in the expected format. It expects a nested hash like this in production environment:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Your `config/secrets.yml` returns a string for the key `production`. Therefore the deployment fails and you were never able to deploy you new version.

Comment: Thank you spickermann, for your reply.

Following your suggestion, I found that the problem was indeed with the secret.yml file.

The reason was a bit different though. While the format was fine, it should not have been tracked by git. Apparently, a secret.yml which is tracked by git can cause this error to happen.

Still, the ruby version is still 2.2.4. I even get now a warning that my Gemfile should contain this string. It does contain 2.3.1. Can it be that the Gemfile is ignored?

Comment: Where does it contain that string? At the top in the second line right below the `source` definition?